# annotate then filter then annotate

Tags: django, annotations

The code:

```
now = datetime.now()
year_ago = now - timedelta(days=365)
category_list = Category.objects.annotate(suma = Sum('operation__value')) \
                                .filter(operation__date__gte = year_ago) \
                                .annotate(podsuma = Sum('operation__value'))
```

The idea: get sum of each category and sum of one year back.

But this code result only filtered objects; `suma` is equal to `podsuma`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A queryset only produces one query, so all annotations are calculated over the same filtered data set. You'll need to do two queries.

**Update:**

Do something like this:

In models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ...
    def suma(self):
        return ...
    def podsuma(self):
        return ...
```

Then remove the annotations and your for loop should work as is. It'll mean a lot more queries, but they'll be simpler, and you can always cache them.

Comment: Ok - so how to solve the problem?  I need it in one queryset - in template there is {for loop}

Comment: I'd write methods on the Category class - I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380392/how-to-add-property-attribute-to-queryset-like-annotation there is the full solution - but thanks for explaining the main problem -